# Column value has been change in a row

Tags: mysql

I have three columns, `Data`, `status` and `count`:

```
Data       Status     count
----------------------------
 1         disable            
 2         disable            
 3         disable
```

This is my pseudo code., `count` is just like a timer:

`count += 1` whenever `table.status` is enabled,

first run looks like this:

```
Data       Status     count
----------------------------
 1         enable       1
 2         disable            
 3         disable
```

Second run:

```
Data       Status     count
----------------------------
 1         disable       1
 2         disable            
 3         disable
```

Third run:

```
Data       Status     count
----------------------------
 1         enable       2
 2         disable            
 3         disable
```

I am just trying if this is possible in a query, procedure or any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table_name set status='enable', count=count+1 where id=1
```

For disable, use another query, without updating count field. Before enabling, if you need update only if this was changed from diabled, check the status before updating. Very simple task.

Another solution, may be using triggers. This is solution by triggers:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER count_upd
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON my_table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        IF NEW.status = "enabled" and OLD.status = "disabled" THEN
            SET NEW.count = OLD.count+1;
        END IF;
END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: im just a beginner here so correct me if i am wrong,  I understand you how the updating process is done, what if two of status has been disabled, the where condition will be wrong.

Comment: id=1 is just an example. You change "1" to id of the row, that you want to be updated. In case, that updates comes from different places in your code, or/and its impossible to you handle status changing, you must use triggers. I updated post with trigger solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to compare the status. If status is updated and changed then add the count. So yes, it is possible to do this in an SQL procedure (trigger).

Comment: could you give me an example of your concept? thanks.